# « Fumer [(détérminant/article+) terme le plus usuel pour le cannabis roulé] » et impacts de changements normatifs au lexique ?

Tags: usage, québec, locutions, lexique

Quand on parle plus précisément du mode de consommation du cannabis<sup>1</sup> par inhalation sous forme de cigarette (c'est-à-dire roulé avec du papier à rouler), on peut rencontrer le verbe [*fumer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fumer) avec [différents](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consommer%20du%20*%2Cfumer%20un%20*%2Cfumer%20du%20*%2Cfumer%20de%20la%20*%2Cfumer%20du%20pot%2Cfumer%20un%20joint%2Cfumer%20un%20splif%2Cfumer%20un%20p%C3%A9tard%2Cfumer%20de%20la%20marijuana%2Cfumer%20de%20la%20marihuana%2Cfumer%20du%20cannabis%2Cfumer%20un%20jig%2Cfumer%20un%20gringo&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cconsommer%20du%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20vin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20lait%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20sucre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20charbon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20poisson%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20tout%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20bois%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20bl%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconsommer%20du%20gaz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cfumer%20un%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20cigare%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20hectare%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20peu%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20champ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20bon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20cigarre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20joint%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20arpent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20petit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20un%20moment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cfumer%20du%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20tabac%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20chanvre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20tout%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20haschisch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20haschich%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20matin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20kif%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20poisson%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20cannabis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20du%20hasch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cfumer%20de%20la%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfumer%20de%20la%20marijuana%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20de%20la%20drogue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfumer%20de%20la%20viande%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfumer%20un%20joint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfumer%20un%20p%C3%A9tard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfumer%20de%20la%20marijuana%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfumer%20du%20cannabis%3B%2Cc0) termes et il semble s'agir de mots désignant (évidemment) la substance et d'autres, le mode ou la forme, dans certains cas par métaphore ou avec des emprunts à d'autres langues etc. :

> Fumer (tout court)... fumer... un joint, un *jig*, un *bat*, un
>   *spliff*, un pétard, un gringo, un bobby, du pot, de la marijuana, marihuana, mari(e), du chanvre, du cannabis, de l'herbe, du foin, une
>   cigarette comique... etc.

- Qu'est-ce que l'on fume le plus (le mot) au Canada francophone (ou
  ailleurs, veuillez svp. préciser où), habituellement, de manière
  courante ou familière, comme lorsqu'on l'offrirait en privé à
  quelqu'un qu'on connaît bien (*voulez-vous/veux-tu fumer
  [(détérminant/article+) terme]?*) ?
- En quoi un changement (normatif, social etc.) touchant une substance (psychotrope) aurait-il un impact sur l'emploi de tel ou tel terme au lexique ; y a-t-il des précédents avec lesquels on pourrait comparer ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Le cannabis réfère soit à la [plante](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8362603) de cannabis soit à la [partie](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870616) de la plante consommée pour ses propriétés psychoactives (GDT). *Le cannabis n'est pas un produit de consommation banal et sa fumée est dangereuse pour la santé* ([SQDC](https://www.sqdc.ca/fr-CA/connaitre-le-cannabis/consommation-responsable)).</sub>

Comment: Je ne consomme pas et ne fréquente à peu près personne d'autre que ma famille immédiate, dans laquelle personne ne consomme. Je ne propose donc pas de réponse, parce que ce serait présomptueux. Mais si je m'y lançais, j'opterais vraisemblablement pour l'ellipse pure et simple: «Est-ce qu'on en/s'en fumerait un (petit)?», avec parfois le verbe *rouler* plutôt que *fumer*.

Comment: Avec plaisir ! Oui essentiellement, même les résultats obtenus sont similaires indépendamment de la tradition juridique. De manière classique : _Iuris praecepta sunt haec : honeste vivere, alterum non laedere, suum cuique tribuere._ (...vivre honnêtement, ne pas faire de tort à autrui, donner à chacun ce qui lui revient. Ulpien dans le Digeste du _Corpus juris civilis_ de Justinien, [1.1.10](https://archive.org/details/corpusjuriscivil01krueuoft/page/xxxii), sur lequel toutes les traditions s'appuient). Par ailleurs, _rendre prévisible_ est un élément essentiel. Merci ! Salutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

À Montréal on va dire "du pot" principalement. D'ailleurs, on utilise déjà le terme comme tel dans certains [articles](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/regional/201810/02/01-5198760-le-pot-interdit-partout-a-quebec.php). "Heille, tu veux-tu fumer du pot?" Sinon, si l'on réfère au joint spécifiquement, je pense que "un bat" est le terme le plus employé. "Viens-t'en, on va s'fumer un bat dehors." Il est important de noter que le français de Montréal est fortement influencé par l'anglais, ça ne reflète donc peut-être pas ce les francophones des autres villes et provinces utilisent le plus fréquemment.

Pour ce qui est de l'aspect social, le cannabis est toléré depuis si longtemps ici que je ne vois pas vraiment de changement quant à comment on y réfère. Par exemple, on va souvent dire en référant à la consommation de drogues dures "faire de la drogue", ou alors être "sur la drogue" en voulant dire sous les effets de la drogue. Ceci est probablement emprunté de l'anglais "doing drugs" et "being on drugs" respectivement. Donc on peut donc souvent entendre "faire de la coke", "faire de la ket" ou bien être "sur l'acide", mais le cannabis va *socio-linguistiquement* être classé avec l'alcool et le tabac; les drogues acceptables. On va donc dire fumer du pot, comme on dirait boire de l'alcool ou fumer la cigarette.

Comment: Merci ! Vous répondez à la question très directement. En passant, si on l'offrait à quelqu'un qui est moins familier avec la langue ou à quelqu'un avec qui on est moins familier, est-ce qu'on pense qu'on aurait tendance à utiliser _cannabis/joint_ ou un autre couple ?

Comment: Je pense qu'il reste quand même un certain tabou (surtout dans le milieu professionnel) par rapport à ça. Si je devais en offrir à quelqu'un que je ne connais pas du tout je pense que j'aurais une approche vague: "Vous fumez-tu de temps-en-temps?" Le contexte devrait être suffisant pour une réponse à la question, même si on ne mentionne pas le cannabis

Comment: Herbe, joint et spliff sont ceux que je connais davantage je crois. Et bat y est plutôt absent, quoiqu'il y a plus longtemps je l'aie utilisé. Merci !